# Unique constraint failed error when saving GeoPackage in QGIS

Tags: qgis, error, geopackage, save, unique-id

In QGIS, when using Processing tools, the temporary output layer in many cases cannot be saved as Geopackage. This happens for example when using ["Explode lines"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=explode#explode-lines) or ["Multipart to Single parts"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=multipart%20singleparts#multipart-to-singleparts), but using other tools as well. When trying to save the output to a GeoPackage, an error message returns:

> Could not make temporary scratch layer permanent.  Error: Feature
> write errors:  Feature creation error (OGR error: failed to execute
> insert :UNIQUE constraint failed: temperror.fid) Only [1](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=explode#explode-lines) of [3]
> features written.

What causes this error and how to save such a layer or make it permanent as a GeoPackage file?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**The short answer: how to solve the problem**

There are at least three possibilities (screenshot for solution 1 and 2 at the bottom):

1. In the export/save dialog, expand `Select fields to export and their export options` and de-select the existing `fid` from export (uncheck the box). QGIS will automatically create a new `fid`-field with unique values.
2. In the `export/save dialog`, expand `Layer Options` and define a new name for the `fid` like `fid_2` to use this as new uniqe id-field. Unique values will be created automatically when you save.
3. Delete the existing `fid` field of the temporary layer before attempting to save it as Geopackage. QGIS will automatically create a new `fid`-field with unique values.

Be aware: solutions 1 and 3 result in loosing the original `fid`-values - so if you intend to use the original `fid` again in the workflow (e.g. for joining), first create an additional attribute like `old_fid` where you copy the values of the original features.

**What causes the error**

The error has to do that the SQlite- (database-) based Geopackage format requires an unique ID for each feature. As a default, the attribute named `fid` is used for that.

The problem now is if you have an input layer that already contains an attribute called `fid` (which normally is the case if the layer's source is a Geopackage) **and** some features of this layer are split up. This is the case with many processing tool like `Explode lines`: one line-feature results in multiple features - one for each segment. Same with  `Multipart to Single parts`: one feature conaining differnt parts is split up to several features - one for each part. The attributes of the newly created features are copied from the orginal layer. So you suddenly have several features with the same `fid` field.

Like this, the unique constrained that defines each feature must have it's own, unique `fid` value is violated and the Geopackage cannot be properly generated. That's why you either have to define a new name for the uniqe-id-field or delete / re-create new values for the existing `fid` field.

*Multipart-polygon split up in singe-part polygons: the `fid`-attribute is taken form the single feature of the original polygon so that all three polygons in the new layer have the same `fid` - this prevents QGIS from saving this layer as Geopackage:*
[image]

*De-selecting the existing `fid` from export (above, solution 1) or re-naming the field that is used as unique `id` to something else like `fid_2`(below, solution 2):*
[image]

Comment: I am curious why this "non-unique" fid problem is specific to Geopackage layers.  It does not happen with other data storage formats, such as shapefiles or FGDB feature classes.

Comment: That's because Geopackage is based on SQLite, thus it is a database format,what is not the case with shapefiles - however I don't know the technical details however and the differences with File Geodata bases. For geopackage, there might be some information here: http://www.geopackage.org/

Comment: Shapefile does not have a real feature id attribute. The features are stored sequentially and for the first feature the fid=1, for the second fid=2 etc. So non-unique fids cannot occur.

Comment: What if the tools that create this problem are re-coded to output a new unique fid, as well as the original (non-unique) fid?