# Create a Grid Cell just for Africa

Tags: qgis

I would like to create a grid cell of 0.5x0.5 degrees just for Africa. I am doing it with *Menu Vector / Research Tools / Create Grid*. However, when I go to select just Africa (extension of the grid) it is a bit difficult (as it can be in the picture). Any idea about how to solve it? I am trying to do it selecting in the attribute table the just African continent but I am still not able to solve it.

My last goal is to have a grid cell for the African Continent. I would like just to see the African Continent with the grid cell.

[image]

Comment: Could you specify your problem, what exactly is the issue with what you got so far? Is it too "wide" including not only continental Africa? What kind of country dataset do you use?

Comment: I would like to restrict the grid cell just to the African Continent. The data that I am using is a layer of all the countries in the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all african countries using the [different selection tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html?#selecting-features) QGIS offers (see screenshot). Hold `Shift` to manually add/remove single countries.

When done copy the selected countries `Menu Edit / Copy features`, than paste them: `Menu Edit / Paste Features As`.

*Screenshot: selecting*
[image]

If you want to keep only the continent, without the countries as individual polygons, on the inserted layer apply `Menu Vector / Geoprocessing Tools / Dissolve`:

[image]

For some reasons, you might want to keep only the continent and not the islands. In this case, use `Menu Vector / Geomtry tools / Multipart to singleparts`. On the resulting layer, select the continent and use Invert selection (`Ctrl+R`) to select all islands. Then delete them (toggle editing mode).

And here you are with the continent left. By the way: by typing `world` into the coordinates box at the bottom of the window, you can load a shapefile-basemap. It is not editable, but you can copy it as described above:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Babel. I am trying to do it but I am not able. I do well the selection of the countries, but when I tried to copy features I do not find this command. I just see copy layer.  Is it the same? On the other hand, is it possible to change the language of the QGIS? I have it in Spanish and I think it will be better if I can change it to English. Thank you again, I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: See here for a translatation of english-language QGIS menu entries etc. into spanish: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qgis/QGIS/master/i18n/qgis_es.ts - search for the english language term to find it's spanish translation: Copy features = Copiar objetos espaciales etc. See here for Copy features (my QGIS is in german): https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtW7S.png - and spanish help for an older QGIS version: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/es/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_gui.html#edit

Comment: Thank you for the links! I have looked in the tool box something call "copiar objetos espaciales" but it does not appear anything. Should I donwload some package?

Comment: Not the toolbox! Menu edit. What menu points do you have?

Comment: Ufff, finally I have found it! In which format I should save it if what I want to do is to join the grid cell? It gives me the following error: "Export to vectorial file failed"

Comment: Try saving as Geopackage, but be aware of this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/400740/unique-constraint-failed-error-when-saving-geopackage-in-qgis

Comment: Dear Babel, thank you so much for your help. I am sorry to disturb you again. I need to do another thing very related with it so I do not know if to write a new post o just write here. I have donwloaded a GRID Cell online. On the other hand, I have done what you tell me in this post, just to maintain the African continent selecting features as you taught me. I would like to restrict the grid cell to the African continent, that is, that the grid cell does not go away from the boundaries of the continent.

Comment: Probably easier to explain in a new post where you can include a screenshot to show what you have and how it should look.

Comment: Thank you. I wil do it!