# Error when trying to export geopackage

Tags: qgis, export, error, geopackage

I'm trying to export a layer which is a geopackage consisting of many linestring shapes. However when I try to export, I get the below error message.

[image: Export to vector file failed]

How to solve this issue?

Comment: If you have an existing field named **fid** it can cause problems when exporting to gpkg. Try exporting using [Refactor Fields](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#qgisrefactorfields) and remove the fid field

Comment: Alternatively, uncheck the **fid** field in the export dialog.  That forces a rebuild of **fid** in the output.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/400741/88814